# VBA Combining Columns

Tags: vba, excel

How do I merge 2 tables using VBA so that it looks like what's below?

**Table 1:**

```
Name          Sales
John Smith    200
John Smith    50
Charles Doe   10
```

**Table 2:**

```
Name          Behavior
John Smith    Website
John Smith    Store
Charles Doe   Store
```

**Combined Table:**

```
Name            Sales   Behavior
John Smith      200     Website
John Smith      200     Store
John Smith      50      Website
John Smith      50      Store
Charles Doe     10      Store
```

Comment: I think you are in the wrong site. SO is not a free coding service, but mainly deals with specific code issues (that is the reason for downvotes). Please try to add some code to your post. I would first think the logical steps needed to complete the task, and then focus in coding each step. For example, take first name, scan table 2 and get behaviors in an array, then scan table 1 and, for each row with that name, write Name, Table1 Sale, and Table 2 Behaviors (that are stored in the array). This approach is resource-consuming, but easy and clear to implement.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I thought about using dictionaries, but my dataset for one table is ~400K rows and the other has about ~1.6K. I ended up using Access to do a cross join where the names are the same. But, this is only short term solution because I'm looking to code it in a way that other people can use it within Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL queries in VBA to process Excel worksheets,Ranges, or Tables as Dataset is the perfect solution to your problem. Infact for large datasets, SQL queries in VBA prove faster than other inbuilt Excel VBA methods.

Below I am providing a boilerplate code around your problem and it will help you in understanding the SQL queries built in Excel, how to use them and then you can search internet for specific issues you have.

```
Sub RunSELECT()
    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql as String

    '---Connecting to the Data Source---
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With


    '---Run the SQL SELECT Query---
    sql =  " SELECT T1.[Name], T1.[Sales], T2.[Behaviour] " & _
         " FROM " & GetRangeAddressfromTableName(Sheet1, "Table1") & " T1  " & _
         "CROSS JOIN " & GetRangeAddressfromTableName(Sheet2, "Table2") & " T2 " & _
         " ORDER BY T1.[Sales] DESC, T1.[Name] "
    Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)

    'Paste the result after SQL execution
    Sheet3.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    '---Clean up---
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetRangeAddressfromTableName(ByRef wks As Worksheet, ByVal tblName As String) As String
    GetRangeAddressfromTableName = "[" & wks.Name & "$" & wks.ListObjects(tblName).Range.Address(0, 0) & "]"
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I modified it to fit my dataset and the desired query. But, when I run it, I get a run-time error: 

The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'TEST$A1:G167313'. Make sure that object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

I did some digging and found that some people saw limitations with this method when the dataset exceeded 65,536 rows. Might that be the issue? For me, the code runs perfectly for datasets with less than 250 rows, but I can't get it to run above that.

Comment: Clearly, 'TEST$A1:G167313' is invalid object name. There should be an exclamation mark between worksheet name and range. A valid name would be 'TEST!$A$1:$G$167313'. Also, select SQL query works perfectly on the dataset exceeding 65536 rows.